# Accessing Labels in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

So I a few **badges** (**MovieClips**)!

[image]

The main idea is to generate a collection of badges with random numbers associated to them.

---

**This is what I did up to now:**

I created two different **MovieClip** badges, and exported them for ActionScript as **Badge** and **BadgeHover**

Within the **BadgeHover** the label has been transformed into a class with instance name **"score"**.

---

---

- ***How do I access this label and change the displayed score?***

  > Do I need to remove and add a new label every time?
- ***What is the best way to add "hover effects"?***

  > What I have is kind of inefficient, I am destroying and recreating the BadgeHover whenever the mouse hovers the Badge class.

---

Help would be very much appreciated! Thanks. :)

Comment: Are the two images provided used for one badge, like the number is normal state and the image (donkey?) is rollover state?

Comment: Thank sberry2A. Both images are for one badge, buth actually the image with the number is the rollover state. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this file out.  Let me know if you have any questions.

http://shaneberry.net/Badges.zip

Comment: Thank you ever so much! I'll try them out! =D

Comment: I hate TinyURL. Usually I look at a URL before clicking to get an idea of what it's about.

Comment: @TandemAdam I'm sure there is some user script that deals with that for you.

Comment: does not exist!